Need to ingest data from redshift database with timestamp data type
I'm using Palantir agent to load data into Foundry via installing agent on Redshift database. I have string, integer and couple of timestamp columns in source data in Redshift. When I sync data into foundry via agent- I need Foundry to interpret timestamp as timestamp or date columns. When I run the sync and store it in the dataset both columns appear as long. Any ideas and fixes on how to make columns in the dataset understand they are timestamp and not long

There is an option in ingestion configuration

you can change it to

if this is not working, then you need to transform it after ingestion.
